# QT Style Comments (Intellisense?)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I noticed in 2.1 of QTCreator, that they now have a sort of intellisense similar to that of Visual Studio. I know intellisense is Microsoft's name for this concept of the helpful tooltip that pops up giving you a description of the method, parameters etc so i don't know what this is **actually** called. Does anyone know how to add these type of pop-up comments to methods and classes in QT?

Again to clarify what i'm talking about are like javadoc comments or the "///" in C#. I'm hoping the devs of QT have a way for the users to make their own comments.

Thanks for the help,

Jec

Comment: It's called "autocompletion".

Comment: it's called Parameter Information in Visual Studio

Comment: Visual Studio also has a feature call Quick Info - tooltips that appear when you hover over a symbol (Parameter Information is a tooltip that appears when you are making a function call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wanting to do this as well.

I found this thread over on qtCentre.org where someone has integrated their own docs into the QT Creator Tooltips.  I haven't tested it myself, but it sounds reasonable:

http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-40324.html?s=98d48c38547da14b0725e5106d83c315

> To use your own documentation in Qt
>   Assistant (and in Qt Creator help as
>   well) you need to create Qt Compressed
>   Help file (.qch
>   (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/assistant-custom-help-viewer.html#displaying-custom-documentation))
>   and register it in Assistant and
>   Creator.  Doxygen has several tools
>   exactly for Qt. There are tags in it's
>   config file, that help you to create
>   the documentation exactly the way you
>   need. E.g. with GENERATE_QHP tag you
>   can make it create the ready qhp
>   (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/assistant-custom-help-viewer.html#creating-a-custom-help-collection-file)
>   (Qt Help Project) file (you need this
>   to generate the .qch). If you don't
>   need to edit this file manually before
>   creating the .qhc, you can set the
>   value of QHG_LOCATION tag to the
>   location of your qhelpgenerator.exe
>   (usually it's here (in Windows):
>   /mingw/bin/qhelpgenerator.exe)
>   and it will generate the ready
>   documentation. Register it in Qt
>   Assistant (optional) and Creator and
>   you're done. After this all your
>   documented types, functions, members,
>   etc. will have the tooltip with F1
>   button hint. And of course pushing F1
>   will show your documented help for it.

Comment: link is broken.